# Go back to previous link in shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I have a simple shiny application (app1) where when the user clicks on the action button (action 1), it is taking to another shiny application(app 2) in another tab.
But there is also another action button (action 2) in app2. So when the user clicks on action 2, it should take him to the previous page(app1). Can we do this?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("aid","Click here")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$aid{
    #### open another link(shiny application) in the browser (different tab)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

very easy, we don't need any server expression, do this:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton(
        "aid", "Click here",
        onclick = 'window.open("https://www.google.com", "_self")'
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

change the link to Google to your app1 link.If you want to open in another tab, remove the `"_self"`.

or this can also work: `onclick = 'location.href = "https://www.google.com";'`

Comment: I have a question. WHen another shiny application opens up. where should I click to get the previous app?

Comment: That's up to you, depends on how you want to design your app. One possibility is to have a link in app A point to app B and a link in app B point to app A.